# An infinite set is countably infinite if it is countable, and is uncountable otherwise

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I find the sentence below from ProofWiki, Definition:Countable Set/Countably Infinite.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Countable_Set/Countably_Infinite

"An infinite is set countably infinite if it is countable, and is uncountable otherwise"

I cannot understand what that means.
The Proofwiki defines the countable sets and the countable infinte separately.

If S is an infinite set and has injective(f:S→N）because S is an countable set,S is a countable infinite because of the existence of the bijection(f:S→N）？？？

Comment: They assume that a set $\{1,2,3\}$ is countable. That's the difference between "countable" and "countably infinite".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right, but if so, I cannot understand the sentence, "An infinite set is countably infinite if it is countable, and is uncountable otherwise.

Comment: I believe it says if S is an infinite set and the injection (f:S→N) exists because S is a a countable set, S is countably infinite because of the existence of bijection( f:S→N）

Answer (score 3):

There are (for these purposes) three kinds of sets:

1. Those that are in bijection with $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n<k\}$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$. These sets are universally called **finite**.
2. Those that are in bijection with $\mathbb N$ itself.
3. All other sets. They are universally called **uncountable** -- or sometimes, for emphasis, **uncountably infinite** which always means the same thing as "uncountable".

Sets of kind 2 or 3 are universally called **infinite**. And everyone agrees that "**countably infinite**" means sets of kind 2.

The word **"countable"** unfortunately has two different meanings. Some people use it to mean "sets of kind 1 or 2"; others use it to mean "sets of kind 2" only.

ProofWiki has chosen to use a [definition for "countable"](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Countable_Set) that happens to hold for exactly the sets of kind 1 and 2. Their only word for kind 2 is then "countably infinite".

The sentence you're quoting then says, more or less:

> Some "infinite" sets are also "countable". The sets that are both "infinite" and "countable" [that is, kind 2] are the ones we call "countably infinite". The sets that are "infinite" but *not* "countable" [that is, of kind 3] are the ones we call "uncountable".

This sentence is not part of their formal definitions, but a consequence of their definitions, which is written down as an informal explanation of how their concepts fit together.

---

In the comments it came to light that you actually do understand what the quoted sentence *means*, but your question is just why it is true.

The technical content of the claim is not quite as trivial as I first said it was. We can unfold the definitions to get

> **Claim**. Let $S$ be a set and $f$ be an injection $S\to\mathbb N$. Then either there is a $k\in\mathbb N$ and a bijection $h:S\to\{n\in \mathbb N\mid n<k\}$, or there is a bijection $h:S\to \mathbb N$.

Informal proof sketch. Let
$$h(s) = \#\{t\in s\mid f(t)<f(s)\}$$
In other words $h(s)$ counts how many other elements of $S$ have *lower* values of $f$ than $s$ does. This has the effect of sliding the function values downwards, but keeping the *ordering* of whether $f(s_1)\lessgtr f(s_2)$. Now if the range of $h$ is *bounded*, then it has a *smallest* upper bound and $S$ was finite. If $h(S)$ is *not* bounded, then it must be all of $\mathbb N$ and $S$ was countably infinite.

This sketch is probably too hand-wavy to count as a real proof at the level of skepticism we're working at here -- for example, I haven't proved that $h$ is injective, or that the range of $h$ is downward closed. To do it more formally we would need to appeal explicitly to induction a few times, which could go something like this:

**Lemma.** Let $S$ and $f$ be given, and let $n\in\mathbb N$ be arbitrary. Then there exists exactly one function $h_n$ such that:

1. The domain of $h_n$ is $\{s\in S\mid f(s)<n\}$.
2. $h_n$ is an injection.
3. For each $m\le n$, there is a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $$\{h_n(s)\mid s\in S, f(s)<m\} = \{i\in\mathbb N\mid i<k\}.$$

The lemma can be proved by induction of $n$. In the induction step we split according to whether $n-1$ is in the range of $f$ or not (since that determines whether we can use $h_{n-1}$ as $h_n$ or we need to extend it with a function value for $f^{-1}(n-1)$. I'll omit the gritty details.

**Second lemma.** If $n<m$ then $h_n\subseteq h_m$.

Proof: Let $h'_n$ be $h_m$ restricted to the domain of $h_n$ (which obviously is a subset of the domain of $h_m$). Then $h'_n$ has all the properties we wanted of $h_n$, and the first lemma said that $h_n$ was the *unique* function with those properties.

Now let $h=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}h_n$. We'll then need to prove

1. $h$ is a function.
2. $h$ is injective.
3. The domain of $h$ is $S$.
4. The range of $h$ is a downwards closed subset of $\mathbb N$.

I'll omit those subproofs; each of them follows relatively directly from known properties of the $h_n$s.

Now if the range of $h$ has *no* upper bound, then since it is downwards closed it must be all of $\mathbb N$, and then we have proved that $S$ is countably infinite.

If the range of $h$ *has* an upper bound, then it must have the form $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n<k\}$ for some $k$ (this is really a separate theorem about bounded and downwards closed subsets of $\mathbb N$, to be proved by induction). In that case $h$ is a witness for the fact that $S$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you so much for you response, you are right and I understand those difference.
But, I cannot understand "An infinite set is countably infinite if it is countable, and is uncountable otherwise."
I believe it says if S is an infinite set and the injection (f:S→N) exists because S is a a countable set, S is countably infinite because of the existence of bijection( f:S→N).
However, I'm not confidence with my recognition and if my recognition is correct, I cannot find the way to prove this.

Comment: I have a bit of trouble grokking how "An infinite set is countably infinite if it is countable, and is uncountable otherwise" is difficult to understand. Do you disagree that my paraphrase in this answer means the same as the sentence?

Comment: Or do you actually _understand what it is the sentence is claiming_ well enough, but merely have trouble seeing why that claim would be _true_?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. 
I cannot understand  the later, why that claim would be true.
I have already known the expression of countable sets in Proofwiki means No1 you mentioned and countable infinite in Proofwiki means No2 you wrote

Comment: @StackOV: Well, if you write "I don't understand _what that means_", you shouldn't expect readers to spontaneously guess that you really meant "I don't understand _why that is true_". Stand by for extension to answer ...

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses, my English is not good, so it is helpful for me.

Comment: @StackOV: Answer extended.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, but It's difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Please check this page.
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Countable_Set
The Proof: Definition 1 implies Definition 2  says
"If  infinite, then it is countably infinite by Infinite Set of Natural Numbers is Countably Infinite, and thus satisfies Definition 2."

So, I wonder if the notion S if countable infinite if S is infinite and has injection f: S→N is concerned with Infinite Set of Natural Number is Countably Infinite:https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Countable_Set

Comment: I'm a beginner so I'd like to understand by formal proof if possible.

Comment: @StackOV: Yes, that is another way to go. If you have a injection $f:S\to\mathbb N$, then $f$ is a bijection _onto its image_. "Infinite Set of Natural Number is Countably Infinite" now gives you a bjection between that image and $\mathbb N$ which you can compose with $f$ to get a bijection all the way from $S$ to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: "I'm a beginner so I'd like to understand by formal proof if possible." Um, that's not really to be recommended. As a beginner you need to have a working intuition before you can properly appreciate the details of the formalization. And just tracking through the proofs in ProofWiki will definitely not show you things in the most instructive order. (...)

Comment: (...) For example its proof of "Infinite Set of Natural Number is Countably Infinite" goes through a lemma that requires the axiom of choice. That's definitely overkill for learning things about $\mathbb N$, even though it may be the most compact way to simply have _all_ the facts proved at the end with no thought to pedagogy, which is (I assume) ProofWiki's goal.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I have to stay relaxed and,  study whole at first.
And then, I'll should focus on details which I have to research.

Comment: But I cannot find out the way to prove.
"Infinite Set of Natural Number is Countably Infinite" is about natural number.
So, if I want to prove X which is infinite set and countable set is countable infinite,
how should I prove ?
By "Infinite Set has Countably Infinite Subset", we have an bijection h: N → M⊆X  , M is countably infinite subset of X because X is infinite.
If we had an injection g: N → X, we would have a bijection f:N → X  by "Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder Theorem/Lemma"  same as  ProofWiki, but 
I cannot find the existence of g.

Comment: @StackOV: A bijection from $\mathbb N$ to a _subset_ of $X$ is also an injection from $\mathbb N$ to $X$.

Comment: oh, no. That's too easy. Thank you so much!!!